# Invisible Buttons

Tags: asp.net

I have a server side ImageButton, and a server side Button, and then a simple HTML input-type="button".  Neither the ImageButton nor the plain HTML button are visible, nor the alt text of the ImageButton.  However, they are rendered out onto the client side HTML when I inspect it.

Anyone have any ideas?

```
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="btnCancel" OnClientClick="top.ChaseDialog.hide();"
                    ImageUrl="~/Images/PageControls/pageControls_Delete_sm.gif" AlternateText="xxxxxxxx"></asp:ImageButton>
```

Comment: can you shows the resulting client side html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say without seeing your full HTML and CSS. A few probable causes:

- Some wrong CSS rule makes them invisible;
- Something else is on top of them;
- Due to auto-resizing of elements they have been compressed to no pixels at all;
- They are outside their container which has `overflow:hidden`;
- The container they are ir is invisible because of the above reasons;

**Added:** I suggest you use some client-side HTML debugger, like "Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar" for IE or "FireBug" for FireFox.

Comment: They were being pushed out of site by a rude piece of text.